# SpatiaLite update/transform Geometry column CRS

Tags: spatialite, sqlite

How do I update the CRS for a table geometry column?

I have created my db and table with

```
spatialite_tool -i -shp London_Ward_CityMerged -d london_boundaries.sqlite -t Barnet -g geometry -c utf-8 -s 27700
```

Then removed a few rows with

```
delete from Barnet where DISTRICT != "Barnet";
```

When I try to update the geometry column with

```
update Barnet set geometry = ST_Transform(geometry, 4326);
```

I get the error

```
Error: Barnet.geometry violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]
```

Comment: Your column is constrained to be 27700 so you can't store 4326 geom in it

Comment: Ah, got it. I created a new column first and then transformed. If you want to provide an answer I will accept it. Or I can just edit my question

Comment: Or you can write that as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment I modified my code to create a geometry column first and then tranform the orignal column into the new one.

```
select AddGeometryColumn("Barnet", "GeometryLatLon", 4326, 'POLYGON', 'XY');
update Barnet set GeometryLatLon = ST_Transform(geometry, 4326);
```